# Coloring some rows in JXTable

Tags: java, swing, jxtable

I have a problem with coloring some rows after resorting columns.
I want to coloring every row which the 4th column equals to zero. So that I have overridden prepareRenderer() method like this:

```
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
    Component comp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
    int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);
    int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel(column);
    double d = (double) getModel().getValueAt(row, 4);
    if(d <= 1e-4){
        comp.setForeground(Color.RED);
    }else{
        comp.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    }
    return comp;
}
```

it works fine. (1st, 2nd and 15th rows colored to red)
[image]

But after sorting some columns this row indices doesnt change.(1st, 2nd and 15th rows red again)
[image]
How to fix it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double d = (double) getModel().getValueAt(row, 4);
```

The data in the model is never sorted so you need to use:

```
double d = (double) getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, 4);
```